# Is there a way to ask a question contrasting the advantages or differences of C# and VB.NET without it being closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I was [told to come ask this here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96854/), so hopefully it doesn't get closed or down voted here too.

I've always been curious why people seem to move from VB to C# when VB.NET seems to have some technical advantages over C#, while both use the same framework and compile down to almost the same code. VB.NET is supported most everywhere C# is in the Microsoft stack.

Is there a way to ask a question about this without it being closed as an ***EXACT DUPLICATE*** of [C# vs VB.NET Debate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/vb-net-vs-c-debate) or some other closed question. Is the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) site not the place to ask questions comparing and contrasting the technical merits of programming languages?

Is it possible to compare things without it being assumed I am asking "Which tech is better?" Better is subjective but technical advantages or merits is objective.

Comment: And the down voting begins without a comment after I was specifically asked to ask this question here by a moderator. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for the record, downvotes on meta don't mean the question is unsuitable. [Votes here are typically used to express agreement or disagreement with whatever the question is about.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Anna so someone disagrees with trying to understand how to ask comparative questions? If the down vote is not in reference to the question then up and down votes shouldn't have reputation attached to them. Otherwise people won't ask tough questions in meta. I see that the FAQ says my rep is not affected by votes, but my reputation screens shows that it changed by votes. Is that a bug?

Comment: I can't say exactly why someone downvoted this question, but it could be someone expressing that they don't think questions like that belong here. Far as the rep goes, your Programmers meta rep is the same as your Programmers rep (though they're not always in perfect sync due to caching). The reputation page on meta doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Are you saying you are unsatisfied with all the other questions and answers given on this subject?

Comment: @Jim, many of my questions are closed now. I think this site is just a kindergarten in which moms (moderators) watch kids (developers) to be a good kid. It's so ridiculous and unfair. I don't know if we can't ask these questions here, where the heck should we?

Comment: @Saeed Stack Exchange sites aren't places where anything goes. They attempt to fill a Q&A niche with a specific format. When there's no SE site to ask your questions at, you can try other forums, Quora, Reddit, etc. You can find some suggestions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've always been curious why people seem to move from VB to C# when VB.NET seems to have some technical advantages over C#, while both use the same framework and compile down to almost the same code. VB.NET is supported most everywhere C# is in the Microsoft stack.
>
> Is there a way to ask a question about this without it being closed as an EXACT DUPLICATE of C# vs VB.NET Debate

I don't think so; I took a look at that question, and it seems to me *all* the answers there are applicable to your proposed question, too.

Your proposed question is by no means bad ... but I do think it's adequately been covered already with answers that have data and graphs and everything.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in a comment on [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96845/why-vb-net-developers-are-migrating-to-c)

> There will be an answer for every developer who switches and each answer will be equally valid.

This means it falls foul of this clause in the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) under the "What kind of questions should I *not* ask here? section:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. [...] **avoid** asking subjective questions where ... every answer is equally valid [...]

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. [...] avoid asking subjective questions where ... every answer is equally valid [...]" Where is a good site/resource for these kinds of subjective questions? Sometimes I just want to bounce ideas or questions off of programmers that are subjective and do indeed have multiple answers. Answers that are all worth considering. As programmers where do you guys go for these kinds of things?

Comment: On the Stack Exchange network, chat - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21 - is probably your best bet.